# Objective-C: Grant Subclass Private Variable Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, instance-variables

I have a class `A` that has an instance variable `NSMutableArray *_onlyVisibleToSubclassesArray`. I would like to grant subclass `B` access to this variable but not any other class `C` which does not subclass `A`.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It violates the whole point of encapsulation. Now you won't be able to change class A without having to worry about how class B is written.

Comment: Hmmmm. You're definitely correct. What should I do then?

Comment: The latter. Edited OP to show this. Isn't the default designation for an ivar `@protected`?

Comment: I don't ever expose ivars, always use properties for exposed access. Since the advent of class extensions only external methods and properties should go in the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `@protected` is, which is the default. Just declare an instance variable in the interface and it will be visible to subclasses and not to sibling classes.

Comment: @rizzes: In general, I don't think it's a great idea because it creates tighter coupling between imementations than is probably necessary. Even within a single class, using properties is usually preferred nowadays. I wouldn't say it's categorically bad, but it's questionable.

Comment: So my code:
`@interface A : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_onlyVisibleToSubclassesArray
}`
Is worse than...what? Putting an @protected @property in the @interface? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
A.h

@interface A : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_onlyVisibleToSubclassesArray
}
```

---

```
B.h

#import "A.h"

@interface B : A
```

In `B.m` I have access to `_onlyVisibleToSubclassesArray`

Another class `C` that imports `A.h`, cannot access _onlyVisibleToSubclassesArray